# Unable to change the layer unit in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, layers, area, units

I have been working with QGIS for 2 weeks and I got the hang of it now.

The problem now is that I cannot calculate the area of a created polygon?
The layer unit is not changing to meters when changing from degrees to meters; it just jumps back?

How to fix this problem?

Comment: What tool are you using to calculate the polygon area? The field calculator?

Comment: What Coordinate Reference System are you using and do you have On The Fly reprojection turned on? (Project => Project Properties => CRS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a layer in degrees, you are using a geodetic coordinate system, like WGS84.

If you want meters as units, you have to save the layer into a projected coordinate system, like UTM.

So Rightlick on the layer entry, `Save As ...` , select a new filename and a different CRS, and add that file to the canvas.

There is no simple way to change the layer units from degree to metres.

Comment: It would be nice if it could perform the calculation without actually having to reproject the data and add it again like in other software that asks in which projection would you like the calculation done